# How to set URL image to AR Core Augmented Image?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

i want set the URL Image to the `aid.addImage("A",bitmap );` bitmap.

here is the code

```
public void setupDatabase(Config config, Session session){

    String URL = "ImageURL.jpg";
    Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),URL);



    System.out.println("bitmap2="+bit);
    AugmentedImageDatabase aid = new AugmentedImageDatabase(session);
    aid.addImage("A",bit );
    config.setAugmentedImageDatabase(aid);

}
```

Comment: did you do it , will you help me if you have done it?

Comment: I need this as well @IamGold and Rahul